# How can I modify my macro to insert multiple photos and position them in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I'm using an Excel macro that inserts only one picture into a specific merged cell. The spreadsheet is designed such that it has multiple sections of 4 merged cells (in a 2x2 format) where the photos are positioned and re-sized into them. Each section has a button at the bottom of the section that prompts the macro and allows me insert one picture. But this gets tiresome since I can only do this with one picture, so I would like to expand the macro by being able to select all 4 photos, insert them, and position them to the specific cells.

The code is shown below:

```
Sub insertpictureinactivecell()
    
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Sh As Shape
    
    Const cFile As String = "Image Files(*.jpg),"
         strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:=cFile)
        If strFile = "False" Then
         Else
          Set rng = ActiveCell
          Set rng = rng.MergeArea
          With rng
           Set Sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=strFile, linktoFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=.Left, Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, Height:=.Height)
           Sh.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
           
        End With
        Set Sh = Nothing
        Set rng = Nothing
        End If
         
    End Sub
```

I've tried Googling multiple solutions for this but I'm still new to Excel VBA so it was difficult for me understand them. Can anyone suggest how to solve this problem?

Comment: You'll need a loop and in each iteration change the top, left etc values accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! Added a for loop, modified my spreadsheet a bit to make spacing between each cell more consistent, and now it works.